# Как установить свойство Text ComboBoxa выделенного элемента в UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.

Есть UserControl, в котором есть `ComboBox`. При изменении значения в `ComboBox` текст выделенного элемента должен присваиваться свойству `Text ComboBoxa`, но он не устанавливается. В окне Window это работает, а в UserControl - нет. Как сделать так, чтобы и в UserControl работало тоже?

```
public partial class ComboBoxControl : UserControl
{
    public ComboBoxControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CheckableCombo.Items.Add("Текст 1");
        CheckableCombo.Items.Add("Текст 2");
        CheckableCombo.Items.Add("Текст 3");
        CheckableCombo.Items.Add("Текст 4");
    }

    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);

            SetText();
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(ComboBoxControl));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ComboBoxControl));

    public string DefaultText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DefaultTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DefaultTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DefaultText", typeof(string), typeof(ComboBoxControl));

    public void CheckableCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetText();
    }

    private void SetText()
    {
        this.Text = (this.ItemsSource != null) ?
            this.ItemsSource.ToString() : this.DefaultText;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text))
        {
            this.Text = CheckableCombo.Items[0].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

.

```
set
{
    SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    SetText();
}
```

Это некорректно. В свойстве-обёртке не должно быть иного содержимого, кроме как вызовов `GetValue` и `SetValue`. Для отслеживания изменения свойства задайте `PropertyChangedCallback` при его регистрации.